# Repetition of letters

Tags: code-golf

Your task is to take an input, for example:

`a,b,4,5`

And produce an output, which per this example is `aaaabbbbb`

`a,b,4,5` means: the lowercase character "a" is repeated 4 times, and is then followed by the lowercase character "b" repeated 5 times, making the total number of characters 4+5=9

Another example: the input `a,B,5,4`, should produce the output `aaaaaBBBB`, which is: the lowercase letter "a" is repeated 5 times, followed by the uppercase letter "B" repeated 4 times.

Some more examples:

```
Input --> Output

a,b,4,6         --> aaaabbbbbb
a,b,c,1,2,3     --> abbccc
a,e,d,f,g,1,2,3,4,5 --> aeedddffffggggg
A,b,4,5         --> AAAAbbbbb
A,b,C,1,2,3     --> AbbCCC
A,B,c,D,1,2,3,4 --> ABBcccDDDD
```

Note how the output must have only the required letters, nothing else, except trailing newlines.

The format of the input should be exactly as you see in the above examples, so your code does not have to support any additional formats/styles of the input.

The output must be displayed in a format exactly as the examples show, this means no commas, spaces, etc, separating the letters. Trailing newlines are okay, if you cannot avoid them.

Standard loopholes are disallowed, and the output is case sensitive.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: will the numbers always be increasing?

Comment: Nope. They don't have to be.

Comment: This seems quite similar to [Run Length Decoding](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12902/12012).

Comment: @ColdGolf Stricter input/output is a pretty trivial modification to a challenge.

Comment: My  challenge's input and output seem to be the *reverse* of the linked challenge.

Comment: Will the numbers always be one digit, as in your examples?

Comment: Nope, not always, they can be anything.

Comment: @ColdGolf can we accept input as a list or list of letter-number pairs? I ask because the language I'm thinking of doesn't do well with string parsing, and it's lists look funny when typed out....

Comment: The input must be the same format as the post.

Comment: Dear administration, it is not the duplicate of the one of link , or if it is, the original one is a question incomprehensible

Answer (score 3):

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), 11 bytes

```
',¡2äøvy`×?
```

**Explanation**

```
',¡             # turn input into a list split at commas
   2ä           # divide that list in 2
       ø        # zip, turning the list into pairs of [letter, number]
        v       # for each pair
         y`×?   # print letter number of times
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=JyzCoTLDpMO4dnlgw5c_&input=QSxCLGMsRCwxLDIsMyw0)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth -  14 bytes

```
Ac2cz\,s*VGsMH
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Ac2cz%5C%2Cs%2aVGsMH&input=A%2CB%2Cc%2CD%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4&debug=0).

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2 - 88 bytes

```py
X=map(str,input().split(','))
k=len(X)/2
print''.join(X[i]*int(X[i+k])for i in range(k))
```

Edited to remove whitespace

Comment: Quoted input is acceptable, so you can do `input()` instead of `raw_input()`. Additionally, you can drop the whitespace between `print` and `''`, and between `)` and `for`. Be sure to take a look at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54/45941 for more golfing suggestions! I've also changed the header to Python 2, because we typically only use "Python" for code that can run under either 2 or 3. Last but certainly not least, welcome to PPCG!

Comment: idk if it'll be shorter, but chopping in half can also be done through `zip(*[iter(foo)]*2)`

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 26 bytes

```
{(∊(//)C⎕VFI⍵)/⍵~⎕D,C←','}
```

Test:

```
          {(∊(//)C⎕VFI⍵)/⍵~⎕D,C←','}'A,b,C,1,2,3'
AbbCCC
```

APL has a built-in for this, so all the code is really doing is parsing the string:

```
      1 2 3/'AbC'
AbbCCC
```

Explanation:

- `⍵~⎕D,C←','`: remove all digits and commas from the input, leaving only the letters. (Since it only has to deal with single letters, this works.)
- `∊(//)C⎕VFI⍵`: using the comma as a field separator, get all valid numbers in the input.
- `/`: replicate each letter by the required amount

Comment: Same basic idea: `{(⍎⍵∩c)/⍵~c←⎕D,','}`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 84 bytes

```
$b=split(',',$argv[1]);while($i<$n=count($b)/2)echo str_repeat($b[+$i],$b[$n+$i++]);
```

Takes the input string as the first argument as in `php script.php a,B,c,3,2,6`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 66 bytes

```
i=input();l=len(i)/2
print''.join(s*y for s,y in zip(i[:l],i[l:]))
```

Uses every Python golfer's favourite function, `zip()`. Takes input with letters in quotes e.g.:

```
'a','b',4,6
```

[**Ideone it!**](https://ideone.com/yGrsWy)