# Text animation format Code Golf

Tags: code-golf, string, conversion

Working with old files from DOS, I found an ancient text animation format, that specify how much time each frame must be shown in the screen. It's very simple:

> F1W5F2W3

This example above indicates that Frame 1 must be shown for 5 units of time, and frame 2 for 3 units more. Now I want to convert it to:

> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2

In the converted example below, frame 1 is repeated 5 times, and frame 2 three times.

**Rules:** The only allowed letters are *F* and *W* (and the lowercase counterparts, *f* and *w*). Numbers can go up to 255. Total input String with no more than 255 chars.

Other examples:

> Input: F10W3F11W3F10W3F12W3
>
> Output: 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12
>
> Input: f1w0f2w10
>
> Output: 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2

**Short code wins.**

**Edited - Accepted formats:**
Any answer containing the output and ignoring spaces. Ex: 1, 1, 2, 2 or [1,1,2,2] or (1,1,2,2). But NOT 1 1 2 2 or [1; 1; 2; 2] or [1 1 2 2].

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Just so you know, [bonuses in code golf](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8106/12012) are discouraged.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information. I have removed the bonus.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this run-length decoding challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12902/20260).

Comment: Not a duplicate, because in the link above the numbers range from 1 to 9 only. This makes a big difference.

Comment: Do we have to support upper and lower case? Or just one or the other?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to output an extra comma at the end of the output?

Comment: Can the output be only comma separated I.e. `10,10,10` instead of `10, 10, 10`?

Comment: I don't see as a problem having spaces (or not) between commas. But it is not acceptable to output an extra comma at the end of the output (just for fairness with other competitors).

Comment: What output formats are accepted, exactly? [1, 1, 2, 2] as in some answers?  [1 1 2 2]? [1; 1; 2; 2]?

Comment: @LuisMendo Edit made for this.

Comment: I don't think having multiple-digit numbers is enough of a difference to make this not a duplicate. It's a very minor change for most solutions, especially the regex-based ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Pyth, 13 bytes

```
smMcr7Xrz0Gd2
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=smMcr7Xrz0Gd2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=F1W5F2W3%0AF10W3F11W3F10W3F12W3%0Af1w0f2w10&debug=0)

This program uses one of my favorite tricks, `mM`, which maps the map function over a list. It is also uses a relic of Pyth's distant past, the `r7` function, which splits a string on whitespace and evaluates the contents, which just so happens to be absolutely perfect for this challenge. Here's how it works, and each intermediate state:

```
smMcr7Xrz0Gd2     f1W5F2w3 

        z        "f1W5F2w3"       Implicit: z is the input.
       r 0       "f1w5f2w3"       Lowercase
      X   Gd     " 1 5 2 3"       Replace all lowercase letters (G) with spaces (d)
    r7           [1, 5, 2, 3]     Split on whitespace, eval each string.
   c        2    [[1, 5], [2, 3]] Split into groups of length 2
 mM                               Apply the map function to each pair
                 [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
s                                 Flatten
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 15):

### Python 3, 57 bytes

```python
lambda s:eval(s.upper().translate({70:'+[',87:']*'})[1:])
```

Turns a string like

```
f1w0f2w10
```

into a expression like

```
[1]*0+[2]*10
```

that it evaluated as code. This is done by turning the string uppercase, turning each `f` into `+[` and each `w` into `]*`, and removing the initial `+`. Thanks to Dennis for saving 7 bytes in Python 3 by using translate with a dictionary.

Comment: `lambda s:eval(s.upper().translate({70:'+[',87:']*'})[1:])` saves 7 bytes in Python 3.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, I'd been trying to get that to work with a list, didn't think to use a dictionary.

Comment: 3 bytes more to have it match the examples: `eval(input().upper().translate({70:'+", ',87:'"*'})[1:])[2:]`

Answer (score 4):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 25 bytes

```
Óá¨ä«©á¨ä«©/²a±, 
D@"hD
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w5PDocKow6TCq8Kpw6HCqMOkwqvCqS_CsmHCsSwgFhsKREAiaEQ&input=RjEwVzNGMTFXM0YxMFczRjEyVzM)

Here is a hexdump of the answer, which is encoded in latin1:

```
0000000: d3e1 a8e4 aba9 e1a8 e4ab a92f b261 b12c  .........../.a.,
0000010: 2016 1b0a 4440 2268 44                    ...D@"hD
```

Explanation:

`<C-v>` is byte `0x16` and `<esc>` is byte `0x1B`. Since they are both unprintable, I am using this notation to refer to them.

```
Óá¨ä«©á¨ä«©/²a±, <C-v><esc>
```

This is a compressed regex, that basically transforms the input into V code. Here's what the buffer looks like after running this regex:

```
3a10, <esc>3a11, <esc>3a10, <esc>3a12, <esc>
```

Here's how that works:

```
3           "3 times:
 a    <esc> "Append the following text:
  10,       " '10, '
```

Running this in V (or its parent, vim) would create:

```
10, 10, 10,
```

And then a similar command repeats for each element of the input.

---

So, after running this regex, we've got valid V code that will create the desired output. Thankfully, V can easily self-interpret, as long as the code is in a buffer. So, we run the following:

```
D      "Delete this line into the unnamed register
 @"    "Run the text in the unnamed register as V code
```

This is exactly what we want, but now the output has a trailing `,`. So:

```
h      "Move one character to the left. Now we are on the second to last character
 D     "Delete until the end of the current line
```

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
r_McvM:z"\d+"1 2 9
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=r_McvM%3Az%22%5Cd%2B%221+2+9&input=F10W3F11W3F10W3F12W3&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=r_McvM%3Az%22%5Cd%2B%221+2+9&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=F1W5F2W3%0AF10W3F11W3F10W3F12W3%0Af1w0f2w10&debug=0)

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 22 bytes

```
t58<*cU2eZ}Y"&D32','XE
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dDU4PCpjVTJlWn1ZIiZEMzInLCdYRQ&input=J0YxMFczRjExVzNGMTBXM0YxMlczJw)

#### Explanation

```
t        % Implicitly input string, say 'F10W2F1W3'. Duplicate
58<      % Array that contains 1 for numeric chars, 0 otherwise: [0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
*        % Multiply element-wise. Converts chars to numeric code
c        % Cast to char. Gives the original string with letters replaced by char 0
U        % Interprets as a numeric array. So the string ' 10 2 4 3' (where spaces are
         % actually char 0) gives the array [10 2 4 3]
2e       % Reshapes into a 2-column array in column-major order: [10 4; 2 3]
Z}       % Split into rows: [10 4], [2 3]
Y"       % Run-length decoding: [10 10 4 4 4]. Implicitly display 
&D       % Get string representation, in the format '[10 10 4 4]'
32','XE  % Replace spaces by commas
```

Comment: Where are the commas? ;-)

Comment: @Chaotic I thought the output format was flexible, as usual. I'll try to solve that later, I'm seeing this on the phone now

Comment: @Chaotic Solved (9 bytes!)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 68 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/F(\d+)W(\d+)/gi,(z,a,b)=>(f=n=>n&&f(n-1,alert(a)))(b))
```

Hopefully an alert box counts as a frame as I couldn't think of another way to count as a 'frame'.

Slightly modified version to try in-browser

```js
t=function(s){s.replace(/F(\d+)W(\d+)/gi,function(z,a,b){(f=function(n){return n&&f(n-1,alert(a))})(b)})}

// Demo
document.getElementById('go').onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = t(document.getElementById('input').value)
};
```

```html
<div style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;"><h2 style="font-family:sans-serif">Text Animation</h2><div><div  style="background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><input placeholder="Input here..." style="resize:none;border:1px solid #DDD;" id="input"><button id='go'>Run!</button></div><br><div style="background-color:#EFEFEF;border-radius:4px;padding:10px;"><span style="font-family:sans-serif;">Output:</span><br><pre id="output" style="background-color:#DEDEDE;padding:1em;border-radius:2px;overflow-x:auto;"></pre></div></div></div>
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `F` in the regex.

Comment: Why are you using `alert`? As I understand the challenge, the output should be as a single list of frames.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 28 bytes

27 bytes of code, plus 1 for the `p` flag in `perl -pe '…'`:

```
s|f(\d+)w(\d+)|"$1
"x$2|gie
```

Output for `F10W3F11W3F10W3F12W3`:

```
10
10
10
11
11
11
10
10
10
12
12
12
```

Comment: The handicap for `-p` is only 1 since you can run as `perl -pe 'code'` which is only 1 character longer than a plain `perl -e 'code'`. So you are actually at 28 bytes :-)

Comment: @TonHospel Scoring flags is so tricky. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 (strict), 8 (relaxed) [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

**Strict input (any upper or lower) & strict output form of a flat list**

```
Œl“wẋ”yṣ”fj“ð;ø”VḊ
```

How?

```
Œl“wẋ”yṣ”fj“ð;ø”VḊ - takes an input, example: F11w7f13W5F17w3f19W2
Œl                 - to lower case            f11w7f13w5f17w3f19w2
  “wẋ”             - make string "wẋ"
      y            - map "w":"ẋ"              f11ẋ7f13ẋ5f17ẋ3f19ẋ2
        ”f         - make string "f"
       s           - split on "f"             [,11ẋ7,13ẋ5,17ẋ3,19ẋ2]
           “ð;ø”   - make string "ð;ø"
          j        - join with "ð;ø"s         ð;ø11ẋ7ð;ø13ẋ5ð;ø17ẋ3ð;ø19ẋ2
                V  - eval Jelly code...
each ẋ will repeat left right times, e.g. 17ẋ3 yields [17,17,17]
; will concatenate,
ð will treat the last chain as a dyadic link (the first will yield 0 as there is no link)
ø will treat the last chain as a niladic link
- so the example evaluates to:
[0, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19]
                 Ḋ - dequeue
[11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19]
```

Test it at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJs4oCcd-G6i-KAnXnhuaPigJ1mauKAnMOwO8O44oCdVuG4ig&input=&args=RjExdzdmMTNXNUYxN3czZjE5VzI)

**Non-strict version: only lower input, returns smashed lists** [a,a,...][b,b,..][...

```
“wẋfø”yv
```

How?

```
“wẋfø”yv - takes an input, example: f11w7f13w5f17w3f19w2
“wẋfø”   - make the string "wẋfø"
      y  - map "w":"ẋ";"f":"ø"      ø11ẋ7ø13ẋ5ø17ẋ3ø19ẋ2
       v - eval Jelly code left with input right (empty)
           this is a hack as V should work (I think)
           but by forcing no input the leading ø evaluates to nothing
evaluation is as above, but simply yields the ẋ lists in turn
- so the example evaluates to:
[11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11][13, 13, 13, 13, 13][17, 17, 17][19, 19]
```

Test it at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4oCcd-G6i2bDuOKAnXl2&input=&args=ZjExdzdmMTN3NWYxN3czZjE5dzI)

Answer (score 2):

### Perl 6, 30 bytes

```
{m:g/\d+/.map:{|(+$^f xx$^w)}}
```

Anonymous function (aka: lambda) which uses a regex match to pull out all the numbers.

I then map over this list, pulling out 2 items at a time using self-declared positional variables `$^f` and `$^w`. Self-declared positional variables are assigned alphabetically, so `f` and `w` works nicely.

The regex match actually produces a list of `Match` objects, so I use the `+` prefix operator to coerce `f` to an `Int`.

The map creates a list of `f`, `w` times. This would normally create a List-of-Lists, so I use the `Slip` prefix operator `|`. A `Slip` is a `List` sub-type that flattens into an outer list, ie. It *slips* a list into the surrounding list, so in the end we get a flat list.

Usage example: `{m:g/\d+/.map:{|(+$^f xx $^w)}}('F1W5F2W3')` returns `(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)`.

Here is the same function written as a full-blown named subroutine, with a more explicit definition.

```pl
sub f(Str $s) {
    ($s ~~ m:g/\d+/).map(-> $f, $w {
        slip( $f.Int xx $w )
    });
}
```

Comment: The space after `xx` isn't necessary. I would have used `.comb(/\d+/)`, I will have to remember to try `m:g/.../` in the future instead.

Comment: My initial solution used comb! I realised the regex match syntax was slightly shorter so I edited my answer. The benefit of using `comb` is that you don't get `Match` objects, so no `Int` coercion necessary inside the map... However, I just [Bench](https://github.com/tony-o/perl6-bench)'d it and the regex is slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), 16 bytes

```
l'f¡vy'w¡`FDïˆ}\
```

**Explanation**

```
                   # implicit input
l                  # convert to lower case: 'f1w5f2w3'
 'f¡               # split on "f": ['','1w5','2w3']
    v              # for each: ex '1w5'
     y'w¡          # split on "w": ['1','5']
         `         # flatten: '5','1'
          FDïˆ}    # N times do; duplicate, convert to int, push to global array: [1,1,1,1,1] 
               \   # discard last copy
                   # implicitly print list at the end of the program
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=bCdmwqF2eSd3wqFgRkTDr8uGfVw&input=RjEwVzNGMTFXM0YxMFczRjEyVzM)

Answer (score 1):

## R, 78 bytes

```
m=strsplit(scan(,""),"[FWfw]")[[1]][-1];cat(rep(m[c(T,F)],m[c(F,T)]),sep=", ")
```

Credit for the `rep(m[c(T,F)],m[c(F,T)])` bit goes to [@flodel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/run-length-decoding/12913#12913).
Usage:

```
> m=strsplit(scan(,""),"[FWfw]")[[1]][-1];cat(rep(m[c(T,F)],m[c(F,T)]),sep=", ")
1: F10W3F11W3F10W3F12W3
2: 
Read 1 item
10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12
> m=strsplit(scan(,""),"[FWfw]")[[1]][-1];cat(rep(m[c(T,F)],m[c(F,T)]),sep=", ")
1: f1w0f2w10
2: 
Read 1 item
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

Comment: Nice one ! I don't get the `m[c(T,F)]` part however...

Comment: @Frédéric `c(T,F)` is the same as `c(TRUE,FALSE)`. This vector will get recycled along the indexed vector, meaning in this case that it will be `TRUE` for each odd member and `FALSE` for each even member, meaning it will return every odd member of `m`. Similarly `c(F,T)` returns every even member.

Comment: Credit for that particular bit of code goes to [flodel](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12913/6741). The linked challenge is very similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 18 bytes

```
r9m_sMdcR\Wtcr1Q\F
```

If you don't need to allow for both upper and lower case, you can take out the `r1` for 16 bytes:

```
r9m_sMdcR\WtcQ\F
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.tryitonline.net/#code=cjltX3NNZGNSXFd0Y3IxUVxG&input=IkYxMFczRjExVzNGMTBXM0YxMlczIg)

Explanation:

```
            c      split:
             r1Q    the uppercase of the input
                \F  on the letter "F"
           t       Remove the first result 
                       The first "F" in the notation has nothing in front of it,
                       so this removes the empty string that prefaces everything
       cR\W        Split each of the results on "W"
  m_               Reverse each of the splits so that the "W" part is first (how many repetitions, then what is to be repeated)  
    sMd            Cast everything within the splits to integers
r9                 Run length decode
```

Comment: If the output format is flexible (and many other solutions assume so), you don't need to stringify or remove the opening/trailing braces which should save 3 chars. Also, why do you need to explicitly cast to integer?

Comment: Explicit cast to integer is to allow run length decoding (which doesn't work with strings as the "key"). I'll remove the stringification.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 32 bytes

**29 bytes code + 3 for `-n`.**

```pl
print"$1 "x$' while/(\d+)w/gi
```

#### Usage

```sh
cat text-animation.pl
print"$1 "x$' while/(\d+)w/gi
perl -n text-animation.pl <<< 'F1W5F2W3'
1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

### Perl, 29 bytes

**26 bytes code + 3 for `-n`.**

If no separator is required, this works:

```
print$1x$' while/(\d+)w/gi
```

Comment: You can fix the separator issue at the cost of 1 byte: `s%\d+w%say for($&+0)x$'%gie` (needs `-E` or `-M5.010` to activate `say`)

Answer (score 1):

### C#, <s>160</s> 155 bytes

```
s=>{var r="";int i=1,j;var t=s.Split('f','F');while(i<t.Length){var u=t[i++].Split('w','W');for(j=0;j++<int.Parse(u[1]);)r+=u[0]+",";}return r.Trim(',');};
```

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, <s>162 bytes</s> 147 bytes

Okay, this is only for fun since it's kinda hard to beat esoteric programming languages but I don't care too much about winning the challenge. I do enjoy solving the challenge, though. Here is my *stab* for this challenge:

```
Function F(a):b=Split(Replace(a,"F","W"),"W"):For i=1To Ubound(b)/2:c="":For j=1To b(2*i):c=c & b(2*i-1) & ",":Next:d=d & c:Next:F=Left(d,Len(d)-1)
```

Ungolfed the code:

```
Function F(a)

b = Split(Replace(a, "F", "W"), "W")

    For i = 1 To UBound(b) / 2
        c = ""
        For j = 1 To b(2 * i)
            c = c & b(2 * i - 1) & ","
        Next
        d = d & c
    Next

F = Left(d, Len(d) - 1)

End Function
```

Explanation:

1. Substitute the letter **F** in the string input with **W** using VBA function Replace.
2. Split the string result with delimited letter **W** into a 1D array.
3. Looping through each element array where every odd element is replicated as many as its next element value (the nearest even element).
4. Concatenate each of looping output.
5. Truncate the output so that the trailing `,` is excluded.

---

Thanks [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for the advice.

Comment: I've never programmed in VBA, so correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't there a `Replace` in VBA which is shorter than `Application.Substitute`? So `b=Split(Replace(a,"F","W"),"W")` instead?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Ahh, you're correct. I didn't use it since it Excel function with 5 arguments, I forgot there is a VBA version of it. Edited. Spasibo.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 68 bytes

```
p""=[]
p(_:b)|[(c,_:d)]<-reads b,[(e,f)]<-reads d=(c+0<$[1..e])++p f
```

Usage example: `p "F1W5F2W3"` -> `[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2]`.

`reads` takes a string and reads something from the front of it and returns a singleton list with a pair of the something and the rest of the string. The type system knows from the usage `c+0` and `[1..e]` that the somethings must be numbers, so `reads` consumes all digits from the beginning of the string. The `_` in the patterns match the letters `F` and `W` that we don't need otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 86 bytes

```
(fn[a](mapcat #(repeat(read-string(last %))(first %))(partition 2 (re-seq #"\d+" a))))
```

Depending on requirements, I could also drop "cat" from "mapcat".

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 67 bytes

```
($args[0]-replace'F','+,'-replace'W','*').trim('+')+'-join", "'|iex
```

Takes input `$args[0]` as a string, pumps it through two `-replace` statements to swap the `F` for a `+,` and the `W` for a `*`. Then `.trim`s the errant initial `+` before concatenating `-join` with a `,<space>`, and piping to `iex` to evaluate the resulting string into a new string. That's left on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

As an example, with input `F1W5F2W3`, after the `-replace`s, our string will be `+,1*5+,2*3`. After the `.trim`, it'll be `,1*5+,2*3`. That's concatenated with the `-join` statement, like `,1*5+,2*3-join", "`. The `iex` then evaluates that string by forming an array of `5` `1`s via the comma-operator, using array concatenation to add on an array of `3` `2`s, so we have an array like `(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2)`, which is then fed into `-join` to put the comma-space between the elements.

Since `-replace` is by default case-insensitive, it handles lowercase as well.

#### Test cases

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\text-animation-format.ps1 'F1W5F2W3'
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\text-animation-format.ps1 'F10W3F11W3F10W3F12W3'
10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 12, 12, 12

PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\text-animation-format.ps1 'f1w0f2w10'
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 51 bytes

Might be able to be golfed further, I'm not super familiar with Retina.

```
i`F(\d+)W(\d+)
$1_$2$*n
(?<=(\d+).*?)n
$1,
\d+_|,$
```

The trailing linefeed is significant.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=aWBGKFxkKylXKFxkKykKJDFfJDIkKm4KKD88PShcZCspLio_KW4KJDEsClxkK198LCQK&input=ZjF3MGYydzEw)

**Explanation:**

The code consists of three replacement stages.

```
i`F(\d+)W(\d+)
$1_$2$*n
```

This replaces each group of `FxWy` into `x_` followed by `n` repeated *y* times. For example, `F2W3` is replaced with `2_nnn`. `` i` `` makes the regex case insensitive.

```
(?<=(\d+).*?)n
$1,
```

This matches all the repeated `n`'s. and replaces each of them with the number closest before it, followed by a comma. Using our previous example of `F2W3`, `2_nnn` is replaced with `2_2,2,2,`.

```
\d+_|,$
```

This removes the final garbage left behind. It replaces the numbers directly followed by underscores, and the comma at the end of the line, with nothing. So `2_2,2,2,` becomes `2,2,2`, which is the desired output.

Comment: Drop the look behind and perhaps and after the capture group reference

Comment: @Downgoat: I'm not entirely sure what you mean... if I drop the lookbehind then it will replace all the `n`s with 1 number, rather than each `n` with the number.